# Wordpress : Need to set zoom level in google embedded map iframe

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I am using Map embed *iframe* with this code  in my Website

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d4911422.152107185!2d-6.743420312530421!3d53.05351610420746!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x487a5d16d99dac79%3A0xbd0539007f0aea54!2s27+Eddisbury+Dr%2C+Newcastle%2C+Staffordshire+ST5+7SL%2C+UK!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1465471022612" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

it looks
[image]

It works good, But i want to set zoom level in this iframe, is it possible?
Guide me how do i set this. Thanks!!

when i am adding this

```
<iframe style="height:100%; width:100%;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=27+Eddisbury+Dr,+Newcastle,+Staffordshire+ST5+7SL,+UK&key=AIzaSyAN0om9mFmy1QN6Wf54tXAowK4eT0ZUPrU&zoom=15"></iframe></div>
```

then I am getting this
[image]

i mean it works , but disturb all page contents and div too.. And when i tried to set its height and width it remains same, means no change.
Back to my question i just want to set zoom level, no need to change height and width or map style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<html>

   <head>
     <title>Google map</title>
   </head>
  <body>
    <iframe style="height:100%; width:100%;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=27+Eddisbury+Dr,+Newcastle,+Staffordshire+ST5+7SL,+UK&key=AIzaSyAN0om9mFmy1QN6Wf54tXAowK4eT0ZUPrU&zoom=15"></iframe></div>
 
  </body>   
</html>
```

**you can use `zoom` variable for zoom level like bellow.**

```
<iframe style="height:100%; width:100%;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=27+Eddisbury+Dr,+Newcastle,+Staffordshire+ST5+7SL,+UK&key=AIzaSyAN0om9mFmy1QN6Wf54tXAowK4eT0ZUPrU&zoom=15"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: sorry my mistake i had place wrong code.
please review edits

Comment: and if it's helpful hit green tick :)

Comment: how did you generate this src which is mention in your question ?

Comment: Visit Google maps  https://www.google.com/maps to create map (Step by step: 1) Find location 2) Click the cog symbol in the top left corner and select "Share or embed map" 3) On modal window select "Embed map" 4) Copy iframe code and paste it).

Comment: see my question again i added screens-shots

Answer (score 21):

I resolved my problem , here i am adding some screen-shots,

I opened the page ,and 
[image]

then it opened like this

[image]

Now go to address bar i.e

[image]
and find out lat long and **Z** associated with lat long
you may change this **Z** as you want and refresh the page

or

[image]

After this go to cog button on top left side i.e

[image]

after this it will open a side bar like this

[image]
then look for share or embed map and click on that it will open

[image]

then
[image]

now copy  iframe code from here and use.
[image]

Thats it. It will work for every one.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me and this should be accepted answer instead of above answer.

Comment: Thanks worked for me and I agree should be the accepted answer as its relevant to the latest version of Google Maps

Comment: Great to know this!

Answer (score 3):

You can try with the &z=nn Some value parameter. It works fine for me. Here is a reference code for you.

```
<iframe width="640" height="480" src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1I8s3COxd2tY0wGKPiBxra1gkE6wpAEx1&z=19"></iframe>
```

Comment: why your embed src is so small, mines is quite big and different. I like ur approach and its working but I am not availble to change the location
my scr is <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d13274.97346178735!2d73.028825!3d33.715589!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x38dfbef8c137888d%3A0xc3ccfd031ad14ba6!2sBahria%20University%20-%20Islamabad%20Campus!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1685727189205!5m2!1sen!2s" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

I did it just by changing "pointer-events: all"
and then you have the same functions as in google map, zoom in-out, make a route and etc.

```
.map iframe {
  pointer-events: all;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
```